# C language, vector of struct, miss something?

Tags: c, vector, struct

This is a part of my program that I want to create a vector of struct

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[501];
    int qtd;
    int linha;
    int coluna;
} tPeca;

tPeca* criarPecas(FILE *pFile, int tam) {
    int i;      
    tPeca *pecaJogo = (tPeca*)malloc(tam*sizeof(tPeca));
    if (pecaJogo == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 1; i <= tam; i++) {
        fscanf (pFile, "%[^;]", pecaJogo[i].nome);  
        fscanf (pFile, "%d", pecaJogo[i].qtd);  
        fscanf (pFile, "%d", pecaJogo[i].linha);
        fscanf (pFile, "%d\n", pecaJogo[i].coluna);
    }
    return pecaJogo;
}
```

If I change

```
tPeca *pecaJogo = (tPeca*)malloc(tam*sizeof(tPeca));  
if (pecaJogo == NULL)  
    return NULL;
```

to

```
tPeca pecaJogo[tam];
```

It works fine but give some warning

```
[Warning] function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

Comment: C arrays start at index 0, So `for(i=1;i<=tam;i++)` should be `for(i=;i<tam;i++)`

Comment: Well, the warning is telling you exactly where your code is wrong. It is incorrect to return an address of a function local variable. The variable goes out of scope as soon as the function exits so it makes no sense to return it (the caller cannot use it without causing undefined behaviour).

Comment: You don't really need to cast from `void *` to any pointer type.

Comment: for reading by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   placing a blank line between code blocks greatly enhances the readability/understandability of the code.

Comment: in C, when calling malloc() (or any of the related family of functions), do not cast the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that

```
tPeca pecaJogo[tam];
```

is a local variable, and as such the whole array is allocated in the stack frame of the function, which means that it will be deallocated along with the stack frame where the function it self is loaded.

The reason it's working is because that causes undefined behavior, on of the outcomes could be that it works correctly, but it's not **really** working correctly, it's just that nothing is overwriting the location where the array was allocated.

By changing the compilation flags or altering the funcion a little bit, it could stop *working*.

Answer (score 2):

The message states it clearly: using `malloc`, you are allocating space that persists once the function that created it, `criarPecas`, returns.  Your change allocates space that gets reclaimed when the function returns, and thus is free to be used for other things, and can thus be overwritten by another part of the program.

If your program is truly "working fine," you may just be getting lucky.